# Significant location change doesn't work on Wifi only devices

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

Correct me if I'm wrong, I have two devices (iPhone), one with sim-card included and wifi connected, other doesn't have an active sim-card but connects to wifi. I was on train to test the significant location change on both devices, only the one with sim-card sent significant location change event. The one without sim-card didn't fire any event even though it still connected to Wifi.

Any link references are appreciated. IMO, does the significant location change only work with cellular data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the significant location change updates location only when the phone swap from a cellular tower to another, so if it is not on the cellular network (without sim card) it can not detect that, and therefore cannot provide a position :)

#### From Apple doc:

> The significant location change service is better suited for apps that want to get the user’s initial location and then only want to know when that location changes. **This service requires the presence of cellular hardware** and delivers events less frequently than the standard location services.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html?hl=p)

Comment: I do think too but unfortunately I couldn't find any evidence to prove that. If you happen to find one please share it, it'd help me very much!

Comment: Thanks nommis! It'd be better if you can provide me with the link reference. May I have the link reference that you found ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! I founded it! Many appreciated to your help!

Comment: I added a "Source" Link in my answer :) it's under the title "Getting the User’s Current Location". It would be great if you could accept my answer also! :)